# Custom Validator asp.net with java script

Tags: asp.net

' Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Name")%>' />

```
        <div>
        </div>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblAnswers" runat="server" AnswerValue='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ID")%>' RepeatDirection="Vertical">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvAnswers"    ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidate" ControlToValidate="rblAnswers" OnServerValidate="user"  Text="Please Select record!" runat="server" />

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

// here is the code behind
  protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in RepPlay.Items)
        {
            UserAnswers oUserAnswer = new UserAnswers();
            oUserAnswer.User_ID = CMSContext.User;
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                var rblAnswers = item.FindControl("rblAnswers") as RadioButtonList;
                string rblAnswer = rblAnswers.SelectedItem.Value;
                if (rblAnswers.SelectedItem == null)
                { 

                }
                oUserAnswer.Answer_ID = Convert.ToInt32(rblAnswer);
                var lblQuestion = (Label)item.FindControl("lblQuestion");
                oUserAnswer.Question_ID = Convert.ToInt32(lblQuestion.Attributes["QuestionValue"]);
            }
            if (CMSContext.User <= 0)
                oUserAnswer.Session = Session.SessionID;
            int userAnswerId = Eskadenia.Framework.Survey.Data.UserAnswerManager.AddUserAnswer(oUserAnswer);


            Eskadenia.Framework.Survey.Entitis.UserSurvey userSurvey = Eskadenia.Framework.Survey.Data.UserSurveyManager.GetByUserIdAndSurveyId(UserId, surveyId);
            userSurvey.EndTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            Eskadenia.Framework.Survey.Data.UserSurveyManager.UpdateUserSurvey(userSurvey);



        }
```